# Converting ICloudBlob.UploadFromStream to Task.Factory.FromAsync(begin,end,params)

Tags: azure, asynchronous, blob

I am trying to convert:

```
blob.UploadFromStream(stream, null, new BlobRequestOptions { RetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), 3) });
```

to

```
                Task uploadStreamTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
                    blob.BeginUploadFromStream,
                    blob.EndUploadFromStream,
                    stream,
                    null);
```

My problem is that above works if it was only the stream paramter that are passed to the beginUploadFromStream. I cant figure out how I make it accept the other parameters as in my first example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code tries to call an overload of the [BeginUploadFromStream-Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.icloudblob.beginuploadfromstream%28v=azure.100%29.aspx) that does not take any parameters - but there is no such overload. In order to create a Task-Async-Pattern from asnychronous methods that require parameters use the generic version of the [FromAsync<>-Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.FromAsync%60%601%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true). You can specify there what parameters the Begin-Method needs.

For the Begin/EndUploadFromStream Method the code would look like this:

```
Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(blob.BeginUploadFromStream, blob.EndUploadFromStream, stream, null);
```

But since you need to pass the *BlobRequestOptions*, too, things get a little more complicated:

The overload of BeginUploadFromStream-Method that accepts a BlobRequestOptions parameter, requires four parameters in total. But there is no overload of the FromAsync<> method that accepts more than three input parameters for the begin method.

**This is how** you can use the FromAsync<> method though:

1. Create an extension method for ICloudBlob.BeginUploadFromStream that requires two parameters (the stream and the BlobRequestOptions) and passes them properly to the original Begin-Method

   ```
   public static class Extensions
   {
       public static IAsyncResult BeginUploadFromStream(this ICloudBlob blob, Stream source, BlobRequestOptions options, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
       {
           return blob.BeginUploadFromStream(source, 
                                             null, 
                                             options, 
                                             null, 
                                             callback, 
                                             state);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use the Async overload to create the Task

   ```
   Task.Factory
       .FromAsync<Stream, BlobRequestOptions>(blob.BeginUploadFromStream,
                                              blob.EndUploadFromStream, 
                                              stream,
                                              options, 
                                              null);
   ```

If you need to pass all four parameters to the BeginUploadFromStream-Method, let me know. I got an idea of how to solve that issue, too.

**Update:**
Here is a solution for a four-parameterd Begin method. I expected the idea to result in something more generic and use less reflection but for now it only works with a EndMethod that does not have a return value.

```
public static Task FromAsync<TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4>(this TaskFactory factory,
                                                         Func<TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, AsyncCallback, object, IAsyncResult> beginMethod,
                                                         Action<IAsyncResult> endMethod,
                                                         TArg1 arg1,
                                                         TArg2 arg2,
                                                         TArg3 arg3,
                                                         TArg4 arg4,
                                                         object state,
                                                         TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
    {
        // create a promise task that will wait until the async stuff is done
        var constructor = typeof(Task).GetConstructor(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new Type[] { typeof(object), typeof(TaskCreationOptions), typeof(bool) }, null);
        var promise = constructor.Invoke(new object[] { state, creationOptions, true }) as Task;

        // perform the async pattern method
        try
        {
            IAsyncResult asyncResult = beginMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, delegate(IAsyncResult iar)
            {
                if (!iar.CompletedSynchronously)
                {
                    // complete the async pattern
                    endMethod(iar);
                    var mFinish = typeof(Task).GetMethod("Finish", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                    mFinish.Invoke(promise, new object[] { true });
                }
            }, state);
            if (asyncResult.CompletedSynchronously)
            {
                // complete the async pattern synchronously
                endMethod(asyncResult);
                var mFinish = typeof(Task).GetMethod("Finish", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                mFinish.Invoke(promise, new object[] { true });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return promise as Task;
    }
```

Comment: thanks. Could not find anything online that did it for all 4 parameters, so if you have the solution, feel free to add it.

Comment: The idea did not turn out as neat as excpected and only works for a four parameter Begin-Method with an end Method of void...